# What is the correct way to create a python dialog that can be reused via "import"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a python application and I need to have a utility dialog that I can access from several places.  I've created the dialog code in its own file.  Here is a minimal example of the way I've written this.

```
import tkinter

class MessageBox():

def __init__(self):
    self.root = tkinter.Tk()
    self.returnVal = False
    frm = tkinter.Frame(self.root)
    btnOk=tkinter.Button(text="Ok")
    btnCancel=tkinter.Button(text="Cancel")
    btnOk['command'] = self.btnOk_action
    btnCancel['command'] = self.btnCancel_action
    btnOk.pack()
    btnCancel.pack()
    frm.pack()
    self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_mod)

def btnOk_action(self):
    self.returnVal=True
    self.root.quit()

def btnCancel_action(self):
    self.root.quit()

def close_mod(self):
    self.root.quit()

def mbox():
    msgbox = MessageBox()
    msgbox.root.mainloop()
    msgbox.root.destroy()
    return msgbox.returnVal
```

Then what I want to do is something like this:

```
import theDialogFile

value=mbox()
print(str(value))
```

When I try this I get an error of "name 'mbox' is not defined"

I've gotten it to work if I use "from theDialogFile import *" which is great but I don't really understand how the importing works.

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Feel free to tear apart my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import `theDialogFile`, everything inside that file becomes an attribute of `theDialogFile`. So, this code would work well in your case:

```
import theDialogFile

value=theDialogFile.mbox()
print(str(value))
```